# Drupal 8 with SimpleSAMLphp

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, simplesamlphp

I would like to use SimpleSAMLphp, in my Drupal 8 installation.  I have added the required modules.  But, when I try to enable the SimpleSAMLphp module, I get the following error:

> SimpleSAMLphp module requires the simplesamlphp library

I have read the help file, but I am still a little confused.  I am not using composer, so my first step is where I am stuck at:

> 1. Make sure you have a working SimpleSAMLphp installation. It needs to be a  standalone installation, which has a "vendor" folder in the
>      root of the project.

Is this to say that installing the module does not install SimpleSAMLphp as a standalone installation? If not, can anyone provide details on how to set that up?

Comment: Since its an old post. can you tell if you were able to resolve your error that it needs simplesamlphp library.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I ever got this resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal SingleSAML module would nto work as prior to this you need to install SAML library on your Project root. Please find steps:

•   Upload SingleSamlphp on root of drupal server

•   Upload SimpleSAMLphp Drupal Module in DRUPAL_DOC_ROOT/modules/contrib

•   we don’t need to install it until SimpleSAMLphp version 1.6 or newer installed and configured to operate as a service provider.

•   This SAML module will help us to have Auth session storage from ADFS which is independent of our DRUPAL_DOC_ROOT session.

•   Install SAML library as per steps provided in https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable

•   Once SAML library configured then only you can proceed for SAML integration with Drupal.

Comment: Why do you have to manually upload the `simplesamlphp_auth` module to `modules/contrib` instead of `composer install drupal/simplesamlphp_auth`?

Comment: Yes, the ideal way to install using composer only.